# Insert and select from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Every user that signs up for the site is given a user id (stored in the database as User_ID), I am using userCake for the login/user management system just to clarify.

I am quite new to MySQL and PHP. I am trying to create a way so that a user can input a link into a form (I have the form created) and then it saves that to the database (new table?). How would I go about;

1. Creating the table structure for that.?
2. Posting the URL to the database.?
3. Retrieving all of the links associated with the User ID.?
4. Displaying all the users links in a list (a list just for testing)?

I have looked around for some time but can't seem to find anything that helps. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think maybe http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-mysql/

other resources are available, I tried "beginning database driven php website" in fav search engine and there is tons and tons of the stuff, i dont think the actual teaching etc can be done in a single post on SO and maybe you should learn to create tables, and query them with a query tool.  once you got that you can then do your first php hello world app.   create a hello world form  then finally hook up database and start then looking at DB security etc.

Comment: also found this http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/ddws/   third result down on google

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at those links for sure!